# PHP, JQuery, AJAX и сохранение в файл

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Доброго времени суток всем! Вопрос следующего характера:
Делаю конструктов веб форм, на пхп, смарти и джиквери. Все выполняется с помощью аякс. Когда нажимаю новый элемент формы - идет запрос в базу и результат добавляется в окно. Теперь когда в окне нажимаю на элемент - могу отредактировать label, name и т.д.. Вопрос: после всего этого как мне готовую форму в окне сохранить в файл?)

Comment: Второй запрос на сервер, а он там пусть сохраняет =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На том же jQuery.аjах отсылаете пары массивом [ключ:значение,ключ:значение,ключ:значение] ,где ключ-имя nаme передаваемого элемента формы.А на сервере данные рассовываете по БД или в файл запись делаете.

Answer (score 1):

Может, я чего-то не понял, может, быдлокод (скорее всего), но как вариант можно так - 
Вашу форму выводить в каком-нибудь диве типа

```
<div id="my_form">...Ваша форма...</div>
```

по клику на кнопку "Сохранить" (или как там ее) берем

```
$('#my_form').html();
```

и отправляем на сервер, где все это дело в файл и сохранится.

Comment: Ну че так сразу грубо, быдлокод) Код вполне цивильный) Да форму я туда именно и помещаю, в такой контейнер, потом аякс запросом отправляю на сервер и пишу в файл. Всем спасибо, разобрался